# Working remedy for acne?

Tags: water, health

I have an oily skin and recently I found an increase of a acne. I have tried various things. Peppermint facewash, mild soap, sandlewood. But so far, the only thing that came close to a solution is a facewash with Tea Tree oil. Are there any other remedies you have tried with success?

Comment: Eat less fatty foods.

Comment: Why fatty foods provoke acne? It drinking Milo increase acnes?

Comment: "Questions about health issues should be directed to your healthcare provider". Consider never asking for health advice from unqualified strangers on the internet who are unable to see you in person and make an informed judgment

Answer (score 4):

[Acne](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acne) is produced by some small [mites](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demodex_folliculorum), which live in the pores of the skin and feed on sebum. Other causes are also possible.

Besides **consulting a dermatologist**, the following have a good chance to work.

- reduce the fat and cholesterol intake from food; at least as an experiment (1-2 weeks should show results, if any), try to go on a vegetables- and fruits-only diet;
- reduce the intake of sugars; this included any juices with added sugar, which include pretty much everything you can buy from a shop;
- increase the skin hygiene; besides washing, try using cleansing masks; consult a dermatologist or a cosmetician;
- increase the room / apartment hygiene; vacuum dust, wash surfaces / rugs / blankets with disinfectants, boil bed sheets, clothes...;
- change clothes (and wash them, possibly boil them in between uses) more often, pajamas and underwear included;

Comment: Erm, your sources contradict your statement - *acne vulgaris* is caused by excess sebum production (which often has hormonal causes), aggravated by bacteria and where links to diet and lifestyle are hard to generalize and often individual. The mites live on nearly every human’s skin as mostly harmless commensals and large populations appear to correlate with *acne rosacea* (whether as cause or effect is yet unclear), which is a completely different skin condition. And while cleanliness is good, excessive skin washing may worsen acne vulgaris and likely also acne rosacea.

Comment: @Stephie: it might be possible I made some confusion, I am not a specialist. That is why I highlighted that a dermatologist is the best option. Regarding `excessive skin washing`: anything excessive should be avoided. Washing, eating, doing sports... Everything must be done with good reasoning and in "good amount".

Answer (score 2):

This may not be the answer you are looking for:...

When I had acne in my 20's a dermatologist medical prescription was the only thing that cleared my skin up to the point where I stopped all the "remedy" madness and just got on with my day.

Comment: Did it worked permanently?

Comment: @XPD  It's my understanding that the Rx does cure acne.  It clears it.  ( Basically it stopped me from spending hours trying to cover the acne)  After 5-10 years I didn't need it.  I haven't needed it the rest of my life.  My skin just cleared.

Comment: tnx bro. What is the most useful medication you found?

Comment: Reminder: Health is generally off  topic on Lifehacks SE - plus, your dermatologist will be way better suited to give you good advice. Acne comes in different forms on different skin types and with therefore different recommendations for treatment.

Comment: Point taken:  ultimately this is what I meant to convey to the OP.  Dr would be better suited than chasing remedies.  Stephie just said it more eloquently.

Comment: @Marinaio sorry, forgot to explicitly ping the OP... my bad.

Answer (score 1):

Acne that breaks out in a specific area is generally a reaction to something like a food additive or a chemical in your laundry soap perhaps.
However that said,  my son had breakouts all over his body that were a deep red surrounding the acne. We could not find the trigger.
What worked for him is "bovine collagen ".
We found the powder form at the bulk barn. 1 spoon mixed in a glass of cocoa before bed every night and in a week, the acne was cleared.
Health stores carry the pill form btw.
And this doesn't eliminate the need for proper hygiene though.